# Change text & Background of a Toggle Button

Tags: excel, vba, toggle

i have a toggle button that can hide me the chart but i want it to be more designed.

I would like that when the chart is **hidden** that the button text is 'Show' and backgroundcolor is Red and when **he is show**, the button is 'Hidden' and background color is Black.

This is my VBA code :

```
Option Explicit

Sub hidechart()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CA").Range("45:74,118:147, 192:220, 265:292")
        .EntireRow.Hidden = Not .EntireRow.Hidden
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then

Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Rows(6).EntireRow.Hidden = True

Else

Rows(4).EntireRow.Hidden = False

Rows(5).EntireRow.Hidden = False

Rows(6).EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If